# Оптимизация вызова функции в циклах C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, производительность, олимпиада

Имеется код

```
int func(int a, int b) {
    do {
        a /= b;
    } while (a % b == 0);
    return a;
}

int main(){
    ...
        for (int j=k; j <= n; j+=k){
            s += func(j, k);
        }
    ...
}
```

Программа ищет сумму чисел [1..n], 1 < n < 1 000 000 000. Причем, числа которые делятся на k должны быть заменены на "наименьший" делитель, например, 6 при k = 3 надо заменить на 2; 9 меняем на 1, т.к. 9 / 3 = 3 и 3 / 3 =1.

Возможно ли оптимизировать время выполнения данного участка кода.
При n = 1000000000, k = 2, например, время выполнения > 1 сек, а ограничение 1 сек.

Comment: Можно оптимизировать алгоритм - это куда надежнее :) Как именно сформулирована исходная задача? (Кстати, к функции - она точно должна один раз делить `a/b`, даже если `a` на `b` не делится?...)

Comment: поддержу предложение по оптимизации алгоритма (для чего нужно знать задачу), но в случае если сам алгоритм уже оптимален (работает с максимальной производительностью) то его можно распаралелить. Сдесь, например, можно распаралелить for, с помощью `openmp` это вообще просто сделать. Главное помнить, что подобная оптимизация может дать неожиданные результаты (выполнение может даже замедлиться из-за синхронизаций и т.п.)

Comment: Надо найти сумму чисел [1..n], 1 < n < 1 000 000 000. Причем, числа которые делятся на k должны быть заменены на "наименьший" делитель, например, 6 при k = 3 надо заменить на 2; 9 меняем на 1, т.к. 9 / 3 = 3 и 3 / 3 =1. Сумму находим через формулу арифметической прогрессии, сумму кратных k убираем тоже через ариф. прогр., а замену делает моя функция

Comment: k задано? Или для всех чисел - просто освобождение от квадратов? Это с какого-то олимпиадного сайта? URL задачи не дадите?

Comment: ввод данных два числа n и k. Это конкурсное задание на hackerearth. На Питоне мой алгоритм вообще по времени не проходит, пришлось вспомнить о плюсах) но и здесь TLE

Comment: Это с какого-то олимпиадного сайта? URL задачи не дадите?

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/en-us/challenges/competitive/may-circuits-20/

Comment: Там простая формула далжна быть. Суммирование по всем числам запускать не надо вообще. Нужно найти сумму чисел от 1 до n по формуле, а потом вычесть часть, которая получается из чисел, замененных на НОД. И да, проверяющая ситема работает в одном потоке, так что openmp тут не поможет

Comment: Действительно, сумму найти не сложно в ответе ниже присутствует она, и в ней же вычитается сумма замененных, т.к. обе последовательности являются арифметическими

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никогда не пытайтесь ускорять код, не подумав о нормальном алгоритме...

```
unsigned long long func(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long k)
{
    if (n < k) return n*(n+1)/2;
    unsigned long m = n/k;
    return n*(n+1)/2 - k*m*(m+1)/2 +func(m,k);
}
```

Если не ошибаюсь, эта функция считает то, что вам надо - сумму чисел от 1 до `n` этих ваших "сокращенных" чисел...

Comment: Спасибо! Работает действительно быстрее))) в решении конкурса Ваш алгоритм не использовал. Буду разбираться с рекурсивным вызовом. Не совсем понимаю как находит сумму "сокращенных" чисел

Comment: Смотрите - представьте, что мы изымаем из 1..n все числа, делящиеся на k. Получаем последовательность k 2k 3k ... mk, где m - то же, что и в программе. Сумма оставшихся в основной последовательности - это n(n+1)/2 минус этот ряд, т.е. k*(сумма 1...m) - это первые два члена. Ну, а дальше мы получаем - деля на k - ту же задачу, но уже для ряда 1 2 3 ... m - откуда и берется рекурсивный вызов.

Comment: Я понимаю как работает рекурсия))) но я не увидел/не дошло... что можно один раз выполнить деление провести ту же операцию с полученным рядом и т.д. Ну и конечно, надо работать над использованием конструкций отличных от ветвлений и циклов. Ведь если не использовать на практике, то и не увидишь в задаче